# Running a query in MVC 4 does not return any results

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to run a query inside a Controller that basically returns the number of times a person has entered a question.  I have a table set up on SQL Server and EnteredBy is the column I'm trying to run a query against.  So far I have had no luck.  I can create a query that returns everything in EnteredBy column, but for now I just want it to return a specific person only so I can run a counter on that. **My current query returns empty sequence.** Here is my code:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult DisplayCount()
    {
        var enteredBy = from m in db.Table
                        where m.EnteredBy.Equals("Persons Name")
                        select m;

        return View(enteredBy);
    }
```

View for DisplayCount:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>DisplayCount</title>

<script>

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div>
Entered by: <br />

@foreach (var m in Model)
{
    
    @m.EnteredBy <br />

}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I know I don't have any counter in place right now, but I would just like to return that specifics persons name in the view each time its encountered line by line.

If anyone can answer me this it would be of great help as I've been stuck on it for like 2 weeks now since MVC and Razor engine are new subject for me.

Thanks

Comment: what does it do right now?  does the query throw an exception?  does it return the wrong results?  does the view render the wrong way?

Comment: The only thing that could be improved is to define the model for your view. Using the @model directive. But I agree with nathan...we really need better information.

Comment: Right now it just returns the Entered by: and nothing else.  But if I remove the where statement in the Controller it will return everyone that has entered the question.

Comment: Check whether you have rows for the person's name that you have queried in SQL Server

Comment: I do. When I run query without the "where" I get returned all the names for that column.